# Getstream Nodejs: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to implement news feed into my app. Yesterday I wrote [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/GetStream/Stream-Example-Nodejs/issues/14) for a nodejs example but today I tried to implement it in my own app and I get the same error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

and it refers to these lines of code:

```
let flatFeed = FeedManager.getNewsFeeds(userId)["timeline_flat"];

  flatFeed
    .get({})
    .then(function(body) {
      let activities = body.results;
      return StreamBackend.enrichActivities(activities);
    })
    .then(function(enrichedActivities) {
      return res.render("feed", {
        location: "feed",
        user: req.user,
        activities: enrichedActivities,
        path: req.url
      });
    })
    .catch(next);
```

and this is how I instantiated FeedManager

```
let stream_node = require("getstream-node");
let FeedManager = stream_node.FeedManager;
```

I get this when I log `FeedManager.getNewsFeeds(userId))`

```
[ flat: { client:
         { apiKey: 'myapikey',
           apiSecret: 'mysecret',
           appId: 'myappid',
           options: [Object],
           version: 'v1.0',
           fayeUrl: 'https://faye.getstream.io/faye',
           fayeClient: null,
           group: 'unspecified',
           subscriptions: {},
           expireTokens: false,
           location: 'us-east',
           baseUrl: 'https://us-east-api.stream-io-api.com/api/',
           handlers: {},
           browser: false,
           node: true },
        slug: 'flat',
        userId: '5a36b5f8c8b6a1a0b5099cc3',
        id: 'flat:5a36b5f8c8b6a1a0b5099cc3',
        token: '8cQoPLYwlH_qY8vrj7Y8gC7jZ0o',
        feedUrl: 'flat/5a36b5f8c8b6a1a0b5099cc3',
        feedTogether: 'flat5a36b5f8c8b6a1a0b5099cc3',
        signature: 'flat5a36b5f8c8b6a1a0b5099cc3 8cQoPLYwlH_qY8vrj7Y8gC7jZ0o',
        notificationChannel: 'site-32687-feed-flat5a36b5f8c8b6a1a0b5099cc3' },
      aggregated: { client:
         { apiKey: 'mykey',
           apiSecret: 'mysecret',
           appId: 'myappid',
           options: [Object],
           version: 'v1.0',
           fayeUrl: 'https://faye.getstream.io/faye',
           fayeClient: null,
           group: 'unspecified',
           subscriptions: {},
           expireTokens: false,
           location: 'us-east',
           baseUrl: 'https://us-east-api.stream-io-api.com/api/',
           handlers: {},
           browser: false,
           node: true },
        slug: 'aggregated',
        userId: '5a36b5f8c8b6a1a0b5099cc3',
        id: 'aggregated:5a36b5f8c8b6a1a0b5099cc3',
        token: '1BK-vEXYKYHJNYCMeuf5VHRjeG0',
        feedUrl: 'aggregated/5a36b5f8c8b6a1a0b5099cc3',
        feedTogether: 'aggregated5a36b5f8c8b6a1a0b5099cc3',
        signature: 'aggregated5a36b5f8c8b6a1a0b5099cc3 1BK-vEXYKYHJNYCMeuf5VHRjeG0',
        notificationChannel: 'site-32687-feed-aggregated5a36b5f8c8b6a1a0b5099cc3' } ]
```

Trace:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at exports.feed_get (/Users/brankozivanovic/Desktop/kafici-api/controllers/userController.js:652:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/brankozivanovic/Desktop/kafici-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/brankozivanovic/Desktop/kafici-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/brankozivanovic/Desktop/kafici-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/brankozivanovic/Desktop/kafici-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/brankozivanovic/Desktop/kafici-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at param (/Users/brankozivanovic/Desktop/kafici-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
    at param (/Users/brankozivanovic/Desktop/kafici-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (/Users/brankozivanovic/Desktop/kafici-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:3)
    at next (/Users/brankozivanovic/Desktop/kafici-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/Users/brankozivanovic/Desktop/kafici-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/Users/brankozivanovic/Desktop/kafici-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/brankozivanovic/Desktop/kafici-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/brankozivanovic/Desktop/kafici-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/brankozivanovic/Desktop/kafici-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/brankozivanovic/Desktop/kafici-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/brankozivanovic/Desktop/kafici-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/Users/brankozivanovic/Desktop/kafici-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/Users/brankozivanovic/Desktop/kafici-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/brankozivanovic/Desktop/kafici-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/brankozivanovic/Desktop/kafici-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/brankozivanovic/Desktop/kafici-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
```

Comment: Ans what's exactly the Question here?

Comment: Demo doesn't seem to be working, and when I tried to implement it in my app the bug is reproduced. I'm interested if there is any workaround here, or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` A full stacktrace would bemore helpful but... The only place `get` appears in that code is on line 4. So it looks like `flatFeed` is undefined. Do you have a newsfeed called `timeline_flat`? If you `console.log(FeedManager.getNewsFeeds(userId))`, what do you get?

Comment: Updated initial post

Comment: The stack trace says the error is at `/Users/brankozivanovic/Desktop/kafici-api/controllers/userController.js`, line 652, column 5. I assume this is line 4 in the snippet above. OK, so that didn't tell me anything new. But the output from `console.log` is interesting. It suggests that object has properties called `flat` and `aggregated`, whereas the documentation says they're called `timeline_flat` and `timeline_aggregated`. And it looks like you've followed the documentation. So maybe you're running a different version. Try `let flatFeed = FeedManager.getNewsFeeds(userId)["flat"];`.